# Material UI Table Header Background Color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize mui TableHeader with a dark background. But currently, I am not able to do so.
I tried with **@mui/styles** but as the React version is 18 I would not be able to use it

can someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

[image: What I want]

dependency List

```
  "dependencies": {
  "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
  "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
  "@nivo/core": "^0.83.0",
  "@nivo/line": "^0.83.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "axios": "^1.4.0",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
  "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "i": "^0.3.7",
  "npm": "^9.8.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-datepicker": "^4.16.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dotenv": "^0.1.3",
  "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
  "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
  "zustand": "^4.3.9"
},

<TableHead>
  <TableRow sx={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
    <TableCell sx={{ color: "white" }}>Header 1</TableCell>
    <TableCell sx={{ color: "white" }}>Header 2</TableCell>
    {/* ... other table headers ... */}
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>

<Table stickyHeader>
  <TableHead sx={{ background: theme.palette.grey[800] }}>
    {/* ... */}
  </TableHead>
  {/* ... */}
</Table>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried to achieve? You should add sx to the TableCell(s) inside the TableHead, like sx={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}

Comment: @gengisdave I have modified the question and added the codes that I have already tried.

Comment: consider using computed styles, like [\`.${tableHeadClasses.root}\`]:{...}

Comment: I already did with computed style @alivarastepour
But thanks for your suggestion

Only thing that is left is using makeStyles but the issue is I cannot make the chages on root level need to create a different variant and will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to add color

```
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiTableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
const TableHead = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "black"
  }
}))(MuiTableHead);

const TableHeaderCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "green"
  }
}))(TableCell);
```

Hre is an example-:

```
 <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableHeaderCell>
            <TableHeaderCell align="right">Calories</TableHeaderCell>
            <TableHeaderCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
            <TableHeaderCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
            <TableHeaderCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
```

Comment: Thanks ayush !!
I would not be able to modify on the root level as I am already using the basic table in some other component.
I need to try using some custom-variant.
Do you have any suggestion like that ?

Comment: This answer uses outdated/deprecated packages that are not compatible with React 18.